# block alarm() in C in Linux

Tags: linux, block, synchronization, alarm

I need a program with time limitation.

So, I used alarm() function to exit program within the time limit.

But I have a problem with synchronization.

In my program there is a critical section, so if timeout happens within critical section then I want to postpone the alarm after the critical section.

Like this:

```
main() {
  alarm(5);
  ...

  disable_alarm();

  //critical section; program shouldn't exit during this section
  {...} 

  enable_alarm(); //if alarm happens during it's disabled, program must exit here.

  ... 
}
```

In this case, which function should I use for `disable_alarm()` and `enable_alarm()`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to install a signal handler.

Something like the following *pseudo-code*:

```
int alarm_received;

my_handler(int sig) {
   alarm_received =1;
}

void disable_alarm(void)
{
  alarm_received = 0;
  signal(SIGALRM, my_handler);
}

void (enable_alarm(void))
{
  if (alarm_received)
    exit(1);
  signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);
}
```

You should probably use sigaction() rather than signal(), since it's a good habit to get into.

Alternatively, sigprocmask() might be the solution you are looking for, depending on precisely what is meant by *blocking* a signal. If a blocked signal stays pending, abd gets delivered when unmasked, sigprocmask() is the simpler solution for your problem.

Comment: Good, but you should declare `volatile sigatomic_t alarm_received;`

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you could also use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html), assuming you want to test at some points if timer has been reached.